# Delete extra brackets in Counterclockwise strict paredit mode

Tags: eclipse, clojure, paredit, counterclockwise

I'm sure the answer to this question is obvious, but I've read the Counterclockwise documentation and searched on the internet and haven't been able to find it. I frequently end up accidentally putting extra brackets, parens, etc while editing Clojure files in Counterclockwise and have not been able to figure out how to delete them without dropping out of strict paredit mode. For example suppose I have the following function:

```
(defn (add-x-y-z)
  [x y z]
  (+ x y z))
```

I've accidentally put parens around the function name, and as far as I can tell there is no way to delete them short of deleting the function name, deleting the extra parens, and typing the function name back in again, or temporarily dropping out of strict paredit mode. Is there any other option for this? For whatever reason, I run into this problem quite frequently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need 'Raise Selection' I believe, which on Mac is Option-R

FYI, you can look at all the key bindings in the preferences window, but as ever can be difficult to find in eclipse. See attached screenshot and notice that I've sorted on 'When' = 'Editing Clojure Source'

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Select the part you want to keep then then "Raise Selection" (Alt-R in Linux). Also, thanks for pointing me to this preferences option.